# Need to improve following UPDATE SQL statement or rewrite so can execute faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2012, ssas-2012

How can I adjust the following `UPDATE` statement?

There are 3000000 rows in the database table and this when I execute the `UPDATE` statement it takes forever to run. I been running this query from last 17 hours and haven't seen the result. But when I execute `select` statement it takes only 2 minutes and 36 seconds. 
q is fact table while a is dimension table.

```
UPDATE q
SET q.[DID] = a.[DID]
FROM [dbo].[CallDetail] q
JOIN [DimSchart] a ON a.[Schart] = q.[Schart]
WHERE q.[DID] IS NULL;
GO
```

Comment: any triggers on table `q`? Are there many indexes on that table? try disabling indexes, then do update and re-enable the indexes.

Comment: Are you seeing duplicates with the `SELECT` statement? What does the query plan look like?

Comment: Try doing the update in batches of 10k records at a time.

Comment: What type of relation is between a and q.. one to many, for example?

Comment: *There is no indexes on the table* - that'll be your issue then... no wonder it's taking a while with 300000 rows.  Put index on the two `Schart` columns and I bet it will run is next to no time

Comment: I am sorry it does have indexes on both tables but when i disable query does not execute it gives an error and i rebuild the indexes and then running query to update 10000 rows taking 8 minutes . How can i put this in while loop so i do not have to worry there are 3528664 rows in the table which are NULL

Comment: what is the data type of SCHART?  Since this appears to be data warehousing can you replicate this in a test environment with a tablock hint?  And can you rewrite this as a merge statement?

Comment: Can you post the table definitions along with indexes and triggers?

Comment: Is there an index on q.DID? ("ID" makes me think indexes...) if so, dropping that index while updating that column is probably necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a temporary table with the pk fields of table CallDetail and the DID field.
2. INSERT into this table a SELECT query which gets CallDetails pk fields and the DID from DimSchart.
3. UPDATE CallDetail from the temp table.

EDIT (added code):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpCallDetailUpdate(CallDetailID int, DID int);

INSERT INTO #tmpCallDetailUpdate(CallDetailID, DID) 
select q.CallDetailID, a.DID
FROM CallDetail q
JOIN DimSchart a ON a.Schart = q.Schart
WHERE q.DID IS NULL;

UPDATE CallDetail q
SET q.DID = u.DID
FROM #tmpCallDetailUpdate u
WHERE u.CallDetailID = q.CallDetailID;
```

(assuming there is a column CallDetailID in your CallDetail table; if not, substitute whatever the PK is on the table.)

Comment: Might might help to "chunkify" this process. Stick an identity column on the temp table, then loop and update for every 10,000 or so rows (id between loopCounter*10000 and loopCounter+1 * 10000

Comment: A loop would be horribly slow.  Doing it as one UPDATE will do the update in a single pass on the table.  NOTE: A Primary key on the temp table might   help (change the first statement to CREATE TABLE #tmpCallDetailUpdate(CallDetailID int, DID int, CONSTRAINT pkTmpCallDetailUpdate PRIMARY KEY(CallDetailID));